# New coupon code comes up as already existing

Tags: coupon

Am trying to create a new coupon code but when I try to save it an error message comes up saying that this code already exists.  I need to use this particular code as have already heavily advertised it.

Comment: And....does it already exist?

Comment: Check in the `salesrule_coupon` table if the code already exists in the `code` column.

Answer (score 1):

As said by Vinai, check the salesrule_coupon table.
If the code exists you see additional fields how often the code can be used per user and how often it can be used etc.

These are some changes your might want to consider. 
Very dangerous in the table itself. The backend of magento gives you also the power to do this.

By now I guess you have lost the big sunday wave so plan your strategy better next time ;)